# How can i create an object in Salesforce that automatically populates any dependent objects?

Tags: salesforce, apex, apex-code

If i need to creat an Order , I need to first creat an Account and then assign the AccountId to the Order, like the following

```
 Account a = new Account();
 a.Name = 'Test';
 insert a;    

 Order order = new Order(     
        AccountId = a.Id,
        Status='Draft',
        EffectiveDate = Date.today());
 insert order;
```

Is there a way I can simply create an Order and the dependent objects will be created or is there a way to get what Sobject field the AccountId of the order is related to ?

Comment: Take a look at [Salesforce StackExchange](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com), there are lots of Q&As on this subject.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way for Salesforce to automatically create the dependent sObjects, they will have to be inserted.

Regarding your second question (retrieving the type of sObject from the field name) you can check out [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/51250/how-to-get-to-which-object-the-field-has-reference) question on Salesforce StackExchange. Below is that code being ran for the AccountId field on the Order object:

[image]